# CSS showing different render behavior on different zoom level

Tags: html, css, browser, sass, render

I created this `Tooltip` element using **HTML** and **CSS**. But after a while I realized that the pointer of my tooltip is getting cut. At first I thought it was some `overflow` issue but it wasn't. Then I tried to change the zoom level of my chrome and I got this

**ZOOM LEVEL <= 250%**

[image: Tooltip Elment]

As you can see the pointer of the tooltip **(highlighted in red)** is getting cut.

**ZOOM LEVEL => 250%**

[image: Tooltip Element]

Now, as you can see the same tooltip on different zoom level worked or rendered just fine.

Anyone can tell me what is the actual problem behind all this or this is a browser issue??

**CODE FOR TOOLTIP**

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip-pointer" data-pointer-direction="bottom"></div>
  <div class="tooltip-content">Hello, World!</div>
</div>
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    max-width: 196px;
    font-weight: 600;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.03125rem;
    background-color: #18191c;
    will-change: opacity, transform;
    box-shadow: 0 5.18px 10.36px -3.89px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

    .tooltip-pointer {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #18191c;

        &[data-pointer-direction='bottom'] {
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I haven't found any solution though instead what I did I change the pointer of tooltips from `HTML` to `SVG` after doing this the tooltip arrows or pointers is not getting cut on different zoom level or any zoom level. If anyone want the code **DM** me.

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing happen before. You could put additional padding or margin underneath the element to allow more space for the tooltip.

Comment: @warnakey it will not work because the position of ```tooltip-pointer``` is already set to absolute.

Comment: would you please share your CSS as well?

Comment: @warnakey did you find any solution??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try creating the down arrow in a different way? Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2jwhnrm3/

HTML

```
<div class="tooltip-pointer"></div>
<div class="tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-content">Hello, World!</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    max-width: 196px;
    font-weight: 600;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.03125rem;
    background-color: #18191c;
    will-change: opacity, transform;
    box-shadow: 0 5.18px 10.36px -3.89px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.tooltip-pointer {
    border: solid red;
    background: red;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 17px;
    left: 50px;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

Comment: Nope it will mess up the entire tooltip system or you can say whole tooltip layout that I have created. I don't want it to change it in anyway SORRY!.

Comment: Okay, not a problem. Sorry I wasn't able to find a good answer to this.

Comment: No Problem!! 